# Retrieving a field in a paragraph with JSON:API

Tags: 8

I have a "user_group" paragraph type which has a user node reference field called "field_group".

Then each user has a paragraph reference field called "field_groups".

So, something like this:

User: field_groups -> paragraph reference with a field_group node reference

Now I need to retrieve all users that have a paragraph which references a given node. So I'm using this JSON:API request:

```
/jsonapi/user/user?filter[field_groups.field_group.id]={some-node-id}
```

But it doesn't return anything. I've also tried:

```
/jsonapi/user/user
?filter[group][condition][path]=field_groups.field_group.id
&filter[group][condition][value]={some-node-id}
```

Which also doesn't return anything.

Any idea on what I'm missing?

**Update:**

I've tried to retrieve paragraphs that reference the node directly:

```
/jsonapi/paragraph/user_group?filter[field_group.id]={some-node-id}
```

But this also didn't return anything... There's no error, but no data returned

Comment: I haven't worked with jsonapi much. But knowing Drupal a bit, iiuc: `field_groups` references a Paragraph `entity` of bundle `user_group` which has a field called `field_group` which references a Node `entity`. So try this notation `field_groups.entity.field_group.entity.id`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work either. No error, but no data returned.